# Sound problems windows 10

Tags: windows, audio

I've been struggling with this extremely frustrating sound problem for at least a year now and have not been able to solve it.

- For reference: I've got an [ASUS Rog Strix Z390-I](https://www.newegg.com/asus-rog-strix-z390-i-gaming/p/N82E16813119159?Item=N82E16813119159).
- Problem: Sound crackling, popping, stuttering, going out of sync. For example, if I'm watching a youtube video for a while, or (more commonly) something on amazon prime, the sound and the video will actually gradually go out of sync. It's insanely annoying. If I'm playing a video game, taxing or otherwise, the sound crackles and pops and stutters unbearably.
- If I plug the audio cable into my monitor (an Acer predator), then the sound problems COMPLETELY go away. But the annoying part here is that the monitor only turns on audio output when the computer is playing sound, which makes a very loud and irritating popping sound every single time.

Here's a screenshot of my [device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbuNg.jpg) if that helps. Let me know if there is any other useful information I can provide, happy to help however I can. Thanks!

Comment: If you are having issues plugging into the 3.5mm jack on the motherboard, but not over the monitor (which is presumably getting audio through HDMI), then you have a sound card issue on your motherboard, probably related to a driver issue. If you have uninstalled the Realtek driver, and installed the latest driver from your manufacturer, then you might need to go to your manufacturer for warranty support on the mobo, due to failures with the integrated audio controller. Latest drivers page > https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z390-I-GAMING/HelpDesk_Download

Comment: I think you're right, I need to talk to Asus.

Comment: Hopefully they help you out! I've run into this problem with a USB audio interface, and it was the audio interface that was failing. Replacing it solved the problem. Unfortunately you can't just replace the integrated audio controller on the motherboard. But, you could add a 3rd party sound card into one of the PCI slots. You might even do this just to troubleshoot that it is indeed your mobo having the problem, and then return the sound card.

Comment: I'll talk to Asus first. If they don't help I'll probably go the soundcard route.